Understanding Parts of Krias Shema al Hamita
Some versions of Krias Shema al Hamita include the following language:

בשם ה' אלוהי ישראל: מימיני מיכאל, משמאלי גבריאל, מלפני אוריאל, מאחורי
רפאל ועל ראשי שכינת אל.

‏Where is the source of this prayer from?
Who instituted it into our nightly prayer?

ב בשם ה׳ אלוהי ישראל-ועל ראשי שכינת אל

Are these two personalities or the same thing?
It seems that God is part of 5 and the most important part is the head!
Can someone enlighten me with sources and help me understand this seemingly obscure Tefillah.

G-d is not made of multiple parts - he is surrounded by His angels all of whom perform a specific function. The final part of "ראשי שכינת קל" is saying that G-d as it were sits highest amongst them.

It is a prayer for protection we are saying: "In the name of G-d, the G-d of Israel, may Michoel be at my right hand; Gavriel at my left; before me, Uriel; behind me, Raphael; and above my head the divine presence of G-d"
